# Blank web page without any error while loading json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I am running this below simple code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Width and height
        var w = 500;1
        var h = 300;

        //Define default path generator
        var path = d3.geo.path();

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        //Load in GeoJSON data
        d3.json("india.json", function(error,json) {
        console.log(json);

            //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
            svg.selectAll("path")
               .data(json.features)
               .enter()
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", path);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run it, i am getting the blank web page without any error. india.json file is a valid json file, i verified it in http://jsonlint.com/

I am new to javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: does the json print in the console? and does the json request have any errors? they wouldnt necessarily automatically print out because its handled by the success handler.

Comment: Yes. it prints all the data, and there is no error in the console

Comment: then the json isnt your problem its how you are setting it up using d3

Comment: but the same code works well with us-states.json file.

Comment: so your code above works? we need to see the part that is broken in order to fix it. how does the json that isn't working compare with the json that does. ps you have a 1 after your width definition which would cause problems

Comment: try referring back to the documentation https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path

Comment: Yes the above code works but not plotting any area. Yeah i realized that "1" after posting here. i deleted that one, but still the same.

Comment: I changed to                                                                                svg.append("path")
    .datum({type: "FeatureCollection", features: features})
    .attr("d", d3.geo.path());                                                                                     but getting the error as features is not defined. However, "features" is there in india.json file

Comment: Did you make sure to do json.features

Comment: thanks @Binvention, it was the problem with projections

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after many trails, i found the solution an it was problem with projection, so i have used the below code and it worked.

```
        //Width and height
        var w = 960
        var h = 1000

        //Define map projection
        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                               .translate([w/2,h/2])
                               .scale(5000);

        //Define path generator
        var path = d3.geo.path()
                         .projection(projection);
```